# How do you state, that plants are seethrough in Minecraft Mods

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Before you read:

I already tested it and this code does still work. but I don't like the error there and the question is just about, if there is another way, because my code right now might not be working in the future.

---

I was following the here linked tutorial series on how to create Minecraft Mods for a while until I got stuck at episode 9.

Tutorial series (can recommend for every newcomer):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpoSy091wYI&list=PLKGarocXCE1HrC60yuTNTGRoZc6hf5Uvl&index=1

Episode I got stuck on (9):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tD0-CHZIeE&list=PLKGarocXCE1HrC60yuTNTGRoZc6hf5Uvl&index=9

The Episode is about how to make a new crop for Minecraft.
At around **4:20** in the video, he adds an line of code and there is the error I have.

He explains, that this line is to make the invisible pixels in the texture actually invisible in the 3D Model later inside the Game.

But here is the problem: That code gives me an error every time I try to write it out.

It always says, that this is wrong, but I don't really understand why. The IDE also says, that the wrong code is **"marked for removal"**

**The line of code looks like this:**

```
@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = MOD_ID, bus = Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD)
    public static class ClientModEvents {

        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void onClientSetup(FMLClientSetupEvent event) {
            ItemBlockRenderTypes.setRenderLayer(ModBlocks.BLUEBERRY_CROP.get(), RenderType.cutout());
        }
    }
```

and is located in the main class of the project called: `TestMod.java`

The exact line I am referring to is this one:
`ItemBlockRenderTypes.setRenderLayer(ModBlocks.BLUEBERRY_CROP.get(), RenderType.cutout());`

The error appears always directly under the `.setRenderLayer()`, so it states, that this is incorrect.

In the video, it was also not strikethrough in the preview, but in my code it was.

I also tried using the other types of `.setRenderlayer()`, but it didnt work.

Here is also an Image how it looks in my IDE:
[image: Picture with the raw code]

[image: Picture with the removal tip]

So my question is:

- Was this updated, so that changed and can't be used like this anymore?
- And if yes, how would you write this now?
- Or do you don't even have to do this anymore?

If anyone wants to replicate this:  I am using *IntelliJ-IDEA*, the *Temurium 17 SDK* and the Mod runs on *Minecraft 1.19(.0)*

Comment: Striken through code in an IDE is usually indicative of a `@Deprecated` annotation, meaning it has been marked as obsolete in the context of minecraft code. It may not necessarily be replaced yet (I've been out of the client code for years), but should still "work" in the meantime. Including an image of the error in this case may actually be of help.

Comment: Alright, will add an image just now @Rogue

Comment: Interesting it's highlighted red, that's preventing you from building? Try adding `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` right above your `@SubscribeEvent` as a temporary workaround (if it works, it's not the final / best solution).

Comment: It actually does not prevent me from building, but I still try to work around any errors/ red underlines @Rogue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.19+, it is no longer advised to set the render types in your code. Instead, you should do it through the JSON file, like this:

```json
{
  "parent": "minecraft:block/crop",
  "textures": {
    "crop": "examplemod:block/blueberry_crop"
  },
  "render_type": "minecraft:cutout"
}
```

There are many variations for `render_type`, such as `minecraft:solid` (which is default), `minecraft:cutout` (which you want for most plants), `minecraft:translucent` (which you want for blocks like stained glass), and many others.

More information about `render_type` can be found on the [official Forge documentation](https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/1.19.x/rendering/modelextensions/rendertypes/).